# Automatically creating Laravel project fails with error: TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable

Tags: php, laravel, docker

This is the output of the command:

```
Step 5/7 : RUN ./vendor/bin/laravel new --force testapp
 ---> Running in dc92e378b12a
Crafting application...
[91m
[0m[91mIn Process.php line 1062:

  TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.


new [--dev] [--force] [--] [<name>]

[0mService 'cli' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./vendor/bin/laravel new --force testapp' returned a non-zero code: 1
[Pipeline] }
```

This is my Docker file:

```
$ cat Dockerfile.cli
FROM php:7.2-cli

COPY composer.json /app/
COPY scripts /app/scripts
RUN composer install --no-dev
RUN ./vendor/bin/laravel new --force testapp

# Define where the Drupal Root is located
ENV WEBROOT=web
```

How can I automaticallly build a Laravel image with a specific set of packages installed to do some testing?

Comment: lucky laravel is geared towards providing their the necessary insights to the users. Just think how such an error - as in this question - would put a halt to those activities that rely on blindly using their overly complex framework without actually knowing what is done behind the scene. .... I run in the same error, and it made me realize how unfriendly this laravel is, with regards to user autonomy.  Why did you choose to install laravel inside a docker container, is it the gazillions of virtually unauditable code it sideloads and which can almost not be trusted?

Answer (score 2):

Only solution I found out to be working fine is to give up on `laravel` command and do this with `composer`:

`RUN composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel testapp`.

Comment: any idea why the OP's command failed? What does the teletype have to do with it? Most importantly, can you see any difference between your alternative command and the OP's command (other of course that the original does not work inside a docker)? Difference I mean with respect to the outcome of having setup a new laravelproject?

Comment: Spent hours trying to figure what was wrong. This worked a treat. Should have tried it when I saw it in there instructions. Very strange error.

Answer (score 0):

Before running

```
RUN ./vendor/bin/laravel new --force testapp
```

include this line:

```
RUN sed -i "s/\$process->setTty(true);/\/\/\$process->setTty(true);/g" ./vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php
```

Making the Dockerfile look like this

```
FROM php:7.2-cli

COPY composer.json /app/
COPY scripts /app/scripts
RUN composer install --no-dev
RUN sed -i "s/\$process->setTty(true);/\/\/\$process->setTty(true);/g" ./vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php
RUN ./vendor/bin/laravel new --force testapp

# Define where the Drupal Root is located
ENV WEBROOT=web
```